# Odd behavior with Maps

Tags: java, dictionary

I am getting a syntax error which I am not able to resolve. I am using Java 1.8.

```
import java.util.*;

public class datatypetest 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Map map1 = new HashMap();
        map1.put("1", "Deepak");
        map1.put("2", "Ajay");
        System.out.println(map1);
        System.out.println(map1.keySet());


        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map1.entrySet())
        {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
        }

    }
}
```

But I am getting this error:

```
incompatible types: Object can not be converted to Entry<String,String>
```

Comment: `Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You created a raw map :

```
Map map1 = new HashMap();
```

Change it to:

```
Map<String,String> map1 = new HashMap<String,String>();
```

If you instantiate the map as a raw `Map`, you can't use `Map.Entry<String, String>` in the loop (you can only use the raw `Map.Entry`).

Comment: You could just say HashMap<> instead of HashMap<String,String> in JDK 1.8

Comment: @almasshaikh as of JDK 7.

Comment: @almasshaikh I guess I'm more comfortable with the Java 6 syntax, as that's the version I'm using at work.

Comment: @almasshaikh JBNizet means that diamond operator is supported in JDK 7 as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Generics to avoid such Type of Conflicts i.e

```
Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Generics provides Type Safety.
And in addition I've found in your code that your Class name didn't follow best practices. It indeed must start with Capital letter since it's a best practice entire JAVA world follows

Try This

```
import java.util.*;
public class DataTypeTest {
   public static void main(String args[]){
       Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
       map1.put("1", "Deepak");
       map1.put("2", "Ajay");
       System.out.println(map1);
       System.out.println(map1.keySet());

       for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map1.entrySet())
       {
           System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
       }

   }
}
```

Happy Programming :)

Answer (score 0):

because you have created 
`Map map1 = new HashMap();`
can be of any type(not just string) so java is not allowing you to downcast it.